# Number of cycles of length $3$ between two adjacent vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Graph $G$ of order $n$ has two adjacent vertices, $u$ and $v$, which are connected by edge $e$. Show that the number of triangles(cycles of length $3$) between $u$ and $v$, which means triangles formed from $u$, $v$ and a common neighbour of them, is at least $d(u) + d(v) - n$. Here $d(x)$ is the degree of a vertex $x$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Tell us about your efforts and observations.

Comment: The number of triangles has to be >= 0. So this means we have to prove that d(u) + d(v) >= n . In a connected graph the sum of degrees for two non-adjacent vertices is >=n-1. Can we claim that since u and v are adjacent , d(u) + d(v) >= n , only if the graph G is connected?

Comment: The value of d(u)+d(v)-n can be negative, and if that is the case then the statement to be proven is trivially true because the number of triangles (even if zero) will always be greater than a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the set of vertices of graph $G$ and $N(x)$ denote the neighbors of vertex $x$. Then it is obvious that $N(u)\cup N(v)\subset V$. Therefore
$$
n=|V|\geq|N(u)|+|N(v)|-|N(u)\cap N(v)|\Rightarrow
|N(u)\cap N(v)|\geq d(u)+d(v)-n. 
$$